# Magento Category manager not working properly

Tags: categories, magento-1.6

When i open category manager in magento it shows me error and screen looks like this

[image]

it appeared after i increased memory limit in .htaccess and php.ini files as i was getting a blank page in frontend. after increasing memory limit frontend is working properly again but above problem is not solved...

Comment: i am sorry i edited my question... thanks

Comment: Do you have any errors in `system.log` or `exception.log`?

Comment: i m not so experienced with magento ... so i searched google and found that these files are located at root/var/log directory... bt i cant find any log directory.... does that mean that i don't have any error or i am at wrong place? i have Mage_Log enabled in admin